# ms sql 2008 - one table , multiple filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm tring to filter products with both `Id` 17 with value 97 and `Id` 6 with value 11.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/616573/2) for this.

In this example, I need to return the row where `fkProductId = 24011`.

Can you help me please?

```
CREATE TABLE AttributeBindings(
    fkProductId int,
    fkAttributeId int,
    fkAttributeValueId int
)

INSERT INTO AttributeBindings (fkProductId, fkAttributeId ,fkAttributeValueId) 
                               VALUES (24011, 17, 97)
INSERT INTO AttributeBindings (fkProductId, fkAttributeId ,fkAttributeValueId) 
                               VALUES (24012, 17, 97)
INSERT INTO AttributeBindings (fkProductId, fkAttributeId ,fkAttributeValueId) 
                               VALUES (24011, 6, 11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join the table on product id:

```
Select p1.fkProductId From AttributeBindings p1
    inner join AttributeBindings p2 on p1.fkProductId = p2.fkProductId
where 
    (p1.fkAttributeId = 17 and p1.fkAttributeValueId = 97)
    and (p2.fkAttributeId = 6 and p2.fkAttributeValueId = 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fkproductid FROM AttributeBindings
WHERE fkAttributeId = 17 AND fkAttributeValueId = 97
intersect
SELECT fkproductid FROM AttributeBindings
WHERE fkAttributeId = 6 AND fkAttributeValueId = 11
```

You can use `INTERSECT` to get the result.

Comment: Hi, if you change "fkproductid" to "fkProductId", it will work. But your quary executes twice time due to Julien's quary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM attributeBindings a
    WHERE a.fkAttributeId = 17
        AND a.fkAttributeValueId = 97
    )
    ,q2
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM attributeBindings a
    WHERE a.fkAttributeId = 6
        AND a.fkAttributeValueId = 11
    )
SELECT q1.fkProductId
FROM q1
INNER JOIN q2 ON q1.fkProductId = q2.fkProductId
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e39a/10/0)